# Code Sniffer Results: The use of function exec() is forbidden

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace

I uploaded new version of extension on `Magento Marketplace`. And I've got Code Sniffer error during technical testing:

```
The use of function exec() is forbidden
severity : 10
Line : 441
Column : 17
Source : Magento2.Security.InsecureFunction.Found
```

How should I replace `exec()` ?

I use server command and cannot just delete `exec()`.

Comment: can you provide info what you are trying to exec?
executing commands will always be unsafe. you should try to implement what the stuff in exec does in PHP

Comment: This is command for exec: identify -ping "/path/to/image/file/phpCB6C.tmp"

Comment: you can definitly do the same in PHP. however "-ping" seems to not to be a valid option. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

Answer (score 1):

use Magento\Framework\ShellInterface

example in Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver (execute method)

Comment: Thank you. It will be useful to know. 

In my case, I solved the problem by deleting **exec()** and use **getimagesize()** instead.

Comment: hi @vitalli, can you update me code to run upgrade command using shellinterface